# How to make my Ubuntu show on a Windows Workgroup

Tags: networking, samba, shared-folders, sharing

I have an Ubuntu (10.10) laptop. In our office everyone is using Windows, and our workgroup is simply `WORKGROUP`. I've installed samba, and its conf is:

```
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   #   security = user

   [share]
   path = /media/Repo/share  // this is another partition
   browsable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   read only = no
   create mask = 0755
```

but still nobody can access my share folder and the machine cannot even be seen on the network. But I can access others shared folders.

Is there anything I needed to do that I left out?

Answer (score 2):

Did you add yourself to samba users?

You can try this GUI to configure it: [system-config-samba](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/system-config-samba) [image: Install Samba]

I did this to configure mine:

**Preferences > Server settings > Basic**: input your Workgroup

**Preferences > Server settings > Security**: Authentication Mode=User, Guest Account=No Guest Account

**Preferences > Samba Users > Add user**:

1. Choose a Linux account (the one Samba will use when accessing the shared files. Usually, you want to choose yourself.)
2. Type in a user name and a password (does not have to be a real windows account or password, its just the input that Ubuntu will ask when someone tries to access the share. It can be "aaa" / "bbb")

So, basically, sharing folders involves two different authentications: first, the one that SAMBA, via SMB protocol, asks for from anyone that tries to access a share. That's step 2 above. Then, after Samba grants that person rights to access the share, Samba itself will need OS authorization to access to the filesystem and its files (the Linux owner-group-world security model). For that, Samba uses the user selected in step 1 above. So any folder (and files) you share must be accessible, inside Linux, by the user selected.

In the Windows world it works the same: there's the *share* authentication and the NTFS one.

Last but not least: whatever user you select (usually yourself), make sure that it has the **Share Files with the Network** privilege in **Administration > Users and Groups > Advanced Settings button > Privileges tab**. I think Ubuntu already grants this privilege to the first user it creates, but it doesn't hurt to check it out.

Also, to share folders, I don't use this GUI, I use Nautilus:

- Right-click the folder you want to share
- Select "Sharing Options"
- Give the share a name, and select read/write or anonymous access

Hope that works for you too!

Comment: what do you have as Unix Username?

Comment: @black sensei: The unix account that Samba will use to access the shared files. Usually, that will be *your* unix login. It means that, after SMB authentication (using the login and password you configured in Samba), it will have the same privileges as you inside that share.

Comment: Ill edit the answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run a simpleHTTP server in the Linux machine and access the same on the other machine.
Steps :

1. first start the terminal from the folder to be shared.
2. run in terminal `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`
3. check your IP using `ifconfig`
4. enter into the browser of the other machine the `ip address:8000`
   eg: if your IP is 127.3.4.123
   Then in browser you type `127.3.4.123:8000`
   you get the required files in the folder to download.